# Why is this login only returning failed? Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, hash, authentication, laravel-5

I've got a custom login code here. As you can see, it's very simple. And we can get as far as the username, but for some reason it never succeeds, I always end up printing a failure.

```
public function postSignIn(Request $request){

        $val = DB::table('ministry')->where('Username', Input::get('Username'))->first();

        if ($val && Hash::check(
            Input::get('Password'), $val->Password)
            ) {
            return redirect()->route('agencydash');
        } return 'failed';
```

I'm unfamiliar with how the Hash facade works, so debugging has been tricky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have encrypted password while creating user

```
$password = Hash::make('yourpassword');
```

then

```
public function postSignIn(Request $request){

        $val = DB::table('ministry')->where('Username', $request->get('Username'))->first();

        if ($val && Hash::check(
            Input::get('Password'), $val->Password)
            ) {
            return redirect()->route('agencydash');
        } return 'failed'; }
```

and if you are still getting error or failed then print  `print_r($val);` after raw query so you can check whether query is failing or not